# Access to the secured property 'sonar.mantis.login.secured' is not possible in preview mode

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

Server:SonarQube4.4
When run sonar-eclipse plugin to analyze my android project,I got a error log like this:

> 19:11:02.596 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 3.0.0 done: 12857 ms
>   19:11:02.650 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor done: 12913 ms 19:11:02.651
>   INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor... 19:11:02.651 INFO  - SonarEngine is used
>   for java 19:11:02.652 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
>   19:11:02.809 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 158 ms 19:11:02.809 INFO 
>   - Sensor MantisSensor... Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar    at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>     at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
>     at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
>   Caused by: Access to the secured property 'sonar.mantis.login.secured'
>   is not possible in preview mode. The SonarQube plugin which requires
>   this property must be deactivated in preview mode.

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to deactivate the Mantis plugin in preview mode.
Through the SonarQube web interface, log in as administrator and then go to Settings > General > General and update the "Plugins excluded for Preview and Incremental modes" property with the key of the Mantis plugin.